# RemoteApp application won't start issue

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

I'd like to ask your help in tackling the following issue:

We store the files of some applications on a file server. The file server can be accessed through a terminal server. The users can reach these applications via RDP icons that launch these applications as RemoteApps.

Following the guides of docs.microsoft.com, I created and published these RDP icons on the terminal server using Powershell.

I successfully created about 10 icons out of which 9 works fine. However, there is one application, that is not very different from the others, that I successfully created a RemoteApp and downloaded the RDP icon from RDWeb of.
When launched, this application asks for the login data to the terminal server but fails to run after that. It can be seen on the tray that it connects to the terminal server, then after a few seconds, it disconnects.

Could you help me figure out why this application doesn't work as a RemoteApp?

If this application isn't launched as a RemoteApp, it works fine.

Comment: Any entries in the event log of the RA Host?

Comment: what do you mean by "deleted the RDP icon from RDWeb of"? Is there any different setup for this problematic app from the other 9 apps? Have you tried to unpublish it and then republish it again?

Comment: Sorry, I mean downloaded it. Edited the post. And yes, I tried to publish then unpublish it several times.